# Профилирование android приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, профилирование

Пожалуйста подскажите как проверить производительность приложения. 
В моем приложении на некоторых устройствах выводится сообщение после некоторого времени

```
Skipped 150 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Ознакомился со многими правилами написания кода, так же включал на физическом устройстве время отработки GPU, уровень прорисовки и т.д. Но необходимо посмотреть какие методы больше всего грузят систему.
Есть ли подобный анализ кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала вам сюда: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

или вот сюда: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview-walkthru.html